# mat-form-field w/ matMatepicker Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm attempting to bind the value from a mat-datepicker to a form control. When I try to do something like 
*[this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlerqrdamjl?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html) I am seeing this error being thrown:*

```
"Uncaught (in promise): Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute"
```

I've tried using formControlName too, but it throws the same error. What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

xhtml

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

typescript

```
  date = new FormControl(new Date());
```

...and with formControlName

xhtml

```
<form-container title="Fake Title">
  <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate="" class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" formControlName="date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
```

typescript

```
  buildForm(): FormGroup {

    return this.formBuilder.group({
      date: [new Date()]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your input a name attribute

Change your code like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput #input [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Tried that, but got the same error. I also tried adding a name attribute to the toggle and picker as well and noticed that the error still says it's an "unspecified name attribute".

Comment: You need to add `#input` to your `<input></input>` tag

Comment: I tried that, and am still getting the same error. :(

Comment: I am using Angular 7 if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce that error with the Stackblitz that you provided. But I did clean it up and provide a number of fixes:

- Add `<form [formGroup]="form">` to the template
- Declare a `form: FormGroup;` in the component
- Inject the `FormBuilder` and call the function to build the form

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.buildForm();
  }
```

- Add `Control` to the control names, i.e. `dateControl`
- Use the `buildForm()` function to set up the form using the Controls

```
  buildForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      date: this.dateControl,
      serializedDate: this.serializedDateControl
    });
  }
```

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evswrc?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html)